# Hadoop tasks: "execvp: permission denied"

Tags: hadoop, exec

In a small Hadoop cluster set up on a number of developer workstations (i.e., they have different local configurations), I have one TaskTracker of 6 that is being problematic. Whenever it receives a task, that task immediately fails with `ChildError`:

```
java.lang.Throwable: Child Error
    at org.apache.hardoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:242)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of 1.
    at org.apache.hardoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:229)
```

When I look at the `stdout` and `stderr` logs for the task, the `stdout` log is empty, and the `stderr` log only has:

```
execvp: Permission denied
```

My jobs complete because the tasktracker eventually gets blacklisted and runs on the other nodes that have no problem running a task. I am not able to get any tasks running on this one node, from any number of jobs, so this is a universal problem.

I have a DataNode running on this node with no issues.

I imagine there might some sort of Java issue here where it is having a hard time spawning a JVM or something...

Answer (score 3):

We have same problem. we fix it by adding 'execute' to below file.

```
$JAVA_HOME/jre/bin/java
```

Because hadoop use $JAVA_HOME/jre/bin/java to spawn task program instead of $JAVA_HOME/bin/java.

If you still have this issue after change the file mode, suggest you use remote debug to find the shell cmd which spawning the task, see [debugging hadoop task](http://srinathsview.blogspot.com/2012/05/debugging-hadoop-task-tracker-job.html)

Answer (score 0):

Whatever it is trying to `execvp` does not have the executable bit set on it.  You can set the executable bit using [`chmod`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod) from the commandline.

Comment: Do you have any idea what it is trying to execvp? Or where I can find that information? This is happening in the internals of the Hadoop framework, and is not something that my job is doing directly.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem.

You can try changing the jdk version 32bit to 64bit or 64bit to 32bit.