# hadoop wordcount example erreor: Task process exit with nonzero status of 1

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am running 3 node cluster on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Server and hadoop 1.2.1 installed on it with JDK 1.7, now for very first check whether map-reduce jobs are executing or not I executed wordcount from hadoop-examples-1.2.1.jar and got the stunning error:

```
14/02/20 20:26:52 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201402202023_0002
14/02/20 20:26:53 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
14/02/20 20:26:57 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id :attempt_201402202023_0002_m_000005_0, Status : FAILED
java.lang.Throwable: Child Error
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:271)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of 1.
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:258)

attempt_201402202023_0002_m_000005_0: execvp: Permission denied
14/02/20 20:27:00 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201402202023_0002_r_000001_0, Status : FAILED
java.lang.Throwable: Child Error
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:271)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of 1.
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:258)

attempt_201402202023_0002_r_000001_0: execvp: Permission denied
14/02/20 20:27:04 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201402202023_0002_m_000005_1, Status : FAILED
java.lang.Throwable: Child Error
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:271)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of 1.
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:258)

attempt_201402202023_0002_m_000005_1: execvp: Permission denied
14/02/20 20:27:07 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201402202023_0002_r_000001_1, Status : FAILED
java.lang.Throwable: Child Error
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:271)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of 1.
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:258)

attempt_201402202023_0002_r_000001_1: execvp: Permission denied
14/02/20 20:27:12 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201402202023_0002_m_000005_2, Status : FAILED
java.lang.Throwable: Child Error
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:271)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of 1.
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:258)
```

After getting this error I executed sqoop import from SQL server 2008 R2 in which I am getting same error. My job's log file also has same error. I also verified by web UI that my cluster's heap size is 200 MB. So, to me memory doesn't seem problematic also userlogs are also there is hadoop.temp.dir (/var/lib/hadoop) and stderr file of logs says:

```
execvp: Permission denied
```

Please let me know what should I do to resolve this issue.

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344572/hadoop-tasks-execvp-permission-denied. This should work for you.

Comment: Thanks Dude...you rock my hadoop world :-)

Comment: Instead of 'thanks' why not to upvote the answer of @acbod?

Comment: I am unable to upvote it !