# Task process exit with nonzero status of 126

Tags: hadoop, java-8

```
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201410200422_0089_m_000002_1, Status : FAILED
java.io.IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of 126.
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:418)

28 May 2015 09:03:19,646 [WARN] (main) org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputhttp://hostname:portNo/tasklog?plaintext=true&taskid=attempt_201410200422_0089_m_000002_1&filter=stdout
28 May 2015 09:03:19,648 [WARN] (main) org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputhttp://hostname:portNo/tasklog?plaintext=true&taskid=attempt_201410200422_0089_m_000002_1&filter=stderr
28 May 2015 09:03:25,672 [INFO] (main) org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201410200422_0089_m_000002_2, Status : FAILED
java.io.IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of 126.
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:418)
```

I went through the given posts - 
[hadoop wordcount example erreor: Task process exit with nonzero status of 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21904354/hadoop-wordcount-example-erreor-task-process-exit-with-nonzero-status-of-1)
[Hadoop tasks: "execvp: permission denied"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344572/hadoop-tasks-execvp-permission-denied%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B)

My stdout file is blank and stderr has

```
bash: /local/apollo/package/local_1/Linux-2.6c2.5-x86_64/JavaSE7/JavaSE7-18.0-0/jdk1.7.0/jre/bin/java: No such file or directory
bash: line 0: exec: /local/apollo/package/local_1/Linux-2.6c2.5-x86_64/JavaSE7/JavaSE7-18.0-0/jdk1.7.0/jre/bin/java: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

I removed all the javase7 dependencies but still it is looked for.
Any pointers how should I go about it?